# Can we check downloading test using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, download

I came through a scenario where i have to check if someone click a link to download something it is downloading properly.. Using selenium is there anyway i can check if it trigger the downloading by clicking the link??

thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With WebDriver you can detect and test any UI changes caused by clicking a link - if the application provides any. E.g. some text appeared `your download was started` or so.

But you'll need to use another approach to test if actual content was downloaded - e.g. test whether a file with certain name appeared in file system. You cannot do this with WebDriver directly - use Java files I\O or other libs for that.